# Do we have tool in linux to manage Stargate (DataStax)?

Tags: cassandra, process, background-process, stargate-oss

I am running Stargate (datastax) in my dev server (Redhat).

```
./starctl --cluster-name xxx --cluster-seed xxx --cluster-version 6.8 --listen xxx --dc DDC --rack rack1 --dse --enable-auth
```

But whenever the session between my local and dev server ends (i log out of dev server), the stargate process also ends.

Do we have a tool in linux to manage stargate process:

. Can make stargate command to run as background process (non stop even after the session ends)

. Can re-run it if stargate suddenly stops.

. If any, can notify by email if after trying to restart stargate 3 times without successful. (this is optional)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need tools to do that. You can just run it in the background with Linux utilities such as `nohup`.

You can also write a shell script that would monitor the process and start it if it's not running.

These things are not specific to Stargate. Any sysadmin can implement these. Cheers!